# Run tests automatically on file save when developing in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have started working with ruby and have been using the Guard gem to run unit tests when a file is modified in the observed directories.

I would like to use something similar in my day job with .Net.

Are there some equivalent tool for .net development ??

Thanks!

Comment: Is not better run it when you build the solution insted? What is the point of rebuild all the solution on each save file event in order to run test that probably will fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/), and it works really well.

I believe there are a few others. The search term that you'd want to use when looking for them is "continuous testing" tools.

Comment: An alternative could be [dotCover](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) by JetBrains, the developers who also made ReSharper.